# WPF,How to insert image into RichTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, richtextbox, flowdocument

Before that, I've seen some ways to do this.
I copy the clipboard image to RichTextBox, but I want to change the size of the inserted image，It's not going to work.

```
 var bmpSource = Clipboard.GetImage() as InteropBitmap;
                    if (bmpSource != null)
                    {
                        RichTextBox.Paste();
                    }
```

In fact, I want to be able to insert images like this.

```
  Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"D:\S.JPG"));
        Image image = new Image();
        image.Source = bitmap;
        image.Width = 120;
        image.Height = 90;
        para.Inlines.Add(new InlineUIContainer(image, EditMessageRTB.Selection.Start));
        EditMessageRTB.Document.Blocks.Add(para);
```

But the RichTextBox of WPF doesn't support this way.
Image insert after the text.it looks like this...

"text,text" [image]

and I want to insert an image like this...
"text," [image] "text"

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a stackpanel in your richtextbox where you add your image.
You can then change the style of the image as you wish, such as:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="bitmap" UriSource="D:\S.JPG"/>
</Window.Resources>

        <RichTextBox>
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>
                    <Run Text="RichTextBox"/>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Screen}" Width="120" Height="80"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Run Text="RichTextBox"/>
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not what I want. The content of RichTextBox is added dynamically,not fixed...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
            FlowDocument fd = new FlowDocument();

            Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
            System.Windows.Controls.Image image = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.BeginInit();
            bi.UriSource = GetUri("Images/ScanHead.png", typeof(PrintService));
            bi.EndInit();
            image.Stretch = Stretch.None;
            image.Source = bi;

            InlineUIContainer b = new InlineUIContainer(image);
            b.BaselineAlignment = BaselineAlignment.Center;
            p.Inlines.Add(b);
            InlineUIContainer b2 = new InlineUIContainer(new TextBlock() { Text="Text\r\n2nd row"});
            p.Inlines.Add(b2);

            p.FontStyle = FontStyles.Normal;
            p.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
            p.FontSize = 18;
            fd.Blocks.Add(p);
```